# Get Indentifier of Android of iOS device (C#)

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have written a function that should give me an Identifier for iOS devices... But now I have to do the same for Android...

Is there an Id witch is on both devices?

Actually im using the AdvertisingIdentifier.

```
    private static string GetIdentifier()
    {
        if (ASIdentifierManager.SharedManager.IsAdvertisingTrackingEnabled)
        {
            return ASIdentifierManager.SharedManager.AdvertisingIdentifier.ToString();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: You want to get the UUID of android device?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT if this is possible, Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't know which ID do you want exactly, I wrote three block of code as follow:

```
//get unique number through TelephonyManager
//use this method, we need to add android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE permission
var telephonymanager = this.GetSystemService(Context.TelephonyService) as TelephonyManager;
var imsid = telephonymanager.SubscriberId;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("imsid: " + imsid);

//get mac address through WifiManager
//use this method, we need to add android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE permission
var wifimanager = this.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService) as WifiManager;
var info = wifimanager.ConnectionInfo;
var macaddress = info.MacAddress;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("mac address: " + macaddress);

//get Android_ID use Android Provider
var deviceid = Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.GetString(this.ContentResolver,
    Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.AndroidId);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("device id: " + deviceid);
```

First one is to get the IMEI, MEID, ESN and IMSI of the phone, which is unique to that piece of hardware. Second one is to get mac address of the device and the last one is to get device id.

All of them can be used to identify the device, you can choose the right one for your scenario. By the way, for the permissions which are needed,  I've commented in the code block.